# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback

Tags: php

I try to using php mvc,how can i fix this error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\Router.php:53 Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\Router.php(53): call_user_func(Array, Object(app\Router))
>
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\public\index.php(20): app\Router->resolve()
>
> #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\Router.php on line 53

here is my `Router`:

```
<?php
/**
 * User: TheCodeholic
 * Date: 10/11/2020
 * Time: 10:05 AM
 */

namespace app;


/**
 * Class Router
 *
 * @author  Zura Sekhniashvili <zurasekhniashvili@gmail.com>
 * @package app
 */
class Router
{
    public array $getRoutes = [];
    public array $postRoutes = [];

    public ?Database $database = null;

    public function __construct(Database $database)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function get($url, $fn)
    {
        $this->getRoutes[$url] = $fn;
    }

    public function post($url, $fn)
    {
        $this->postRoutes[$url] = $fn;
    }

    public function resolve()
    {
        $method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        $url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';

        if ($method === 'get') {
            $fn = $this->getRoutes[$url] ?? null;
        } else {
            $fn = $this->postRoutes[$url] ?? null;
        }
        if (!$fn) {
            echo 'Page not found';
            exit;
        }
        echo call_user_func([$fn], $this);
    }

    public function renderView($view, $params = [])
    {
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
        }
        ob_start();
        include __DIR__."/views/$view.php";
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        include __DIR__."/views/_layout.php";
    }
}
```

and this is `index.php`:

```
<?php

use app\controllers\ProductController;
use app\Router;

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$database = new \app\Database();
$router = new Router($database);

$router->get('/', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
$router->get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
$router->get('/products/index', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
$router->get('/products/create', [ProductController::class, 'create']);
$router->post('/products/create', [ProductController::class, 'create']);
$router->get('/products/update', [ProductController::class, 'update']);
$router->post('/products/update', [ProductController::class, 'update']);
$router->post('/products/delete', [ProductController::class, 'delete']);

$router->resolve();
```

Comment: You need to inspect `$fn` to make sure it is callable. You are manually wrapping that variable in an array, is that needed? Is it already an array?

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> string(33) "app\controllers\ProductController" [1]=> string(5) "index" }` this is value of `$fn`

Comment: Looking at that, I would think you could change to `echo call_user_func($fn, $this);`, removing the square brackets around it.

Comment: I removed that brackets But the error has not yet been fixed

Comment: Please share more details. Is the error message really exactly the same after removing the brackets? Also, what does that ProductController class contain?

Comment: Your code appears to be a custom router that is inspired by other routers such as Laravel that support the syntax `[ProductController::class, 'index']`. From PHP's perspective, that syntax is only valid if the `index` method is marked as static. To access a non-static method, you need an instance to be bound to. The simple and naïve way would be to use `[new ProductController(), 'index']`, however that would mean creating a bunch of new instances. The other frameworks solve this be using that class as a hint into their DI system which is a bigger topic to handle.

Comment: You can see a little bit how Laravel [parses](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a13e74fc710ff3654d5cf064aa648ec9e35f7925/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteAction.php#L20) that using some [reflection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a13e74fc710ff3654d5cf064aa648ec9e35f7925/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteAction.php#L74)

Comment: @ChrisHaas the error fixed, thank you 

Answer (score 1):

According to your replies it seems like your function which was passed to the array is not a correct callable.

Autoload is not a problem as assumed because then the last part of the error message would be  class 'xx' not found.

i suggest to change your router and add callabale typehints and you might see the error earlier.

```
public function get($url, callable  $fn)
{
    $this->getRoutes[$url] = $fn;
}

public function post($url, callable $fn)
{
    $this->postRoutes[$url] = $fn;
}

   public function resolve()
    {
        $method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        $url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';

        if ($method === 'get') {
            $fn = $this->getRoutes[$url] ?? null;
        } else {
            $fn = $this->postRoutes[$url] ?? null;
        }
        if (!$fn) {
            echo 'Page not found';
            exit;
        }
        echo call_user_func($fn, $this);
    }
```

then it will work.

i would also not mix a router with a view.

Comment: Please share more details.  Which parts of the given error message make you think that there is any problem with the autoloader? "Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members" does not mention any such problems

Comment: @NicoHaase youre right, i saw only the error in the title, not in the post

Comment: @VitalijMik i replaced my code with your code , error changed. , this is new error:  `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: app\Router::get(): Argument #2 ($fn) must be of type callable, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\public\index.php on line 11 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\Router.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\public\index.php(11): app\Router->get('/', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\03_good\Router.php on line 28` and i shared my `index.php` for more details